# Passing String Arrays into PHP file with Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, retrofit

I'm trying to use retrofit and PHP to store values in MySQL. I will pass in to the PHP a single postid string (postid) and a string array. For each index in the string array (called tags) I will make a unique row in the database. It will have the following form:

```
--------------------
|postid    |  tags  |
--------------------
| postid   | tags[0]|
| postid   | tags[1]|
| postid   | tags[2]|
....................
--------------------
```

The issue I am having is that for the string array, only the last value in the array is being stored.

Here is the retrofit interface

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("create_recipe.php")
Call<Void> createRecipe(
        @Field("postid") String postid,
        @Field("tags") String[] tags
);
```

and the retrofit client call

```
Retrofit retrofit = ApiClient.getClient();
                                ApiInterface apiService = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

                                Call<Void> call = apiService.createRecipe(postid, tags);
                                call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {

                                    }
                                });
```

Here is what the PHP that handles this looks like (excluding some of the init code)

```
if (isset($_POST['postid']) && isset($_POST['tags']){
$uid = $_POST['postid'];
$tags = array($_POST['tags']);  
$tags_new = str_replace(array('[', ',', ']'), '' , $tags);

foreach ($tags_new as $value){
          mysql_query("INSERT INTO Tags(postid, tag) VALUES('$postid', '$value')");
}

}
```

If I pass in postid = 30 and tags = {"milk", "cheese", "bread"} I want it to look like

```
--------------------
|postid    |  tags  |
--------------------
| 30   | milk      |
| 30   | cheese    |
| 30   | bread     |
....................
--------------------
```

but instead only bread will be stored.

How do I handle the string array passed in as a parameter in PHP?

What is the form of the array when I pass it onto $tags?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some time back and found no clear solution for it. However I built a simple solution for something similar. I hope [this solution](https://gist.github.com/valdio/f3129f8c7da85838b9c04e6f1bb8d498) helps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can print it out in the PHP work sheet, you can add the following to log the input here.

```
file_put_contents("test.log",json_encode($_POST)."--".json_encode($_GET));
```

Only then will you be able to determine whether the array is correctly delivered to the php script.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to reconsider about this, because the following line is basically just removing all the barriers in the string($tags, which is now interpreted as a String instead of an array):

```
$tags_new = str_replace(array('[', ',', ']'), '' , $tags);
```

and change it into

$tags_new = split(',' , $tags);

Comment: Thank you. Just out of curiosity, do you happen to know what the form of the String array is when passed into PHP?

Comment: I will try to debug it like you showed below to find the form as well.